# Using MIN() in SET statement MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update, min

I am using MySQL. Lets call a table that I have as `Inventory` which looks is below:

`+----+--------+--------+-------------+----------+
| ID | Price1 | Price2 | TargetPrice | Quantity |
+----+--------+--------+-------------+----------+
|  1 |     12 |      1 |             |        0 |
|  2 |      3 |      3 |           3 |        2 |
|  3 |        |      4 |             |        0 |
|  4 |      2 |      2 |           2 |        2 |
|  5 |      5 |     45 |           5 |        1 |
+----+--------+--------+-------------+----------+`

Now, I need to update the TargetPrice to minimum of Price1 and Price2 for any row whose Quantity is 0

I have tried:

`UPDATE Inventory SET
TargetPrice= MIN(Price1,Price2) 
WHERE Quantity >0`

However, MySQL complains about the usage of MIN() function. I know it is expecting MIN() to work on the data contained inside column, rather than taking  MIN() of two columns of a specified row.

Anyway to achieve this other than cursors?

**EDIT:**
`Price1` and `Price2` can be `null` or `0` and in all these cases, it should be treated as infinity so that the other price gets to be minimum when compared against it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [**LEAST**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) instead of `MIN`:

```
UPDATE Inventory 
SET TargetPrice = LEAST(Price1,Price2) 
WHERE Quantity = 0
```

`MIN` is an aggregate function operating on a rowset, whereas `LEAST` operates on the list of arguments passed.

**EDIT:**

```
UPDATE Inventory 
SET TargetPrice = LEAST(COALESCE(Price1, Price2), COALESCE(Price2, Price1))  
WHERE Quantity = 0
```

You can use [**COALESCE**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to handle `NULL` values.

**EDIT2:**

You can use [**NULLIF**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif) to handle `0` values:

```
UPDATE Inventory 
SET TargetPrice = LEAST(COALESCE(NULLIF(Price1,0), Price2), 
                        COALESCE(NULLIF(Price2,0), Price1))  
WHERE Quantity = 0
```

Comment: Thank you. However, for ID=3, Price 1 is null, and hence the above LEAST() is returning NULL. I want to return Price 2 in this case. So essentially, of the two prices if any one of them is 0 or null, I need to return the other price, and for all other conditions, the mathematical min. Any help around that pls?

Comment: Thx again. The reason I was not using `COALESCE` is it handles only NULL. I needed to handle 0 also as similar behavior to NULL. Though I didn't have a sample data in my original question, I have changed it now to include this requirement. Probably `CASE` can help? But then if both a NULL (we need to report a NULL)?